# adding the time and getting the average in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table on my database.

```
+--------- --------- ------------+
|   id    |   time  |    date    |
+--------- --------- ------------+
|    1    |   0:12  | 03/30/2014 |
 --------- --------- ------------
|    2    |   0:14  | 04/09/2014 | <-- date today
 --------- --------- ------------
|    3    |   0:32  | 04/09/2014 | <-- date today
 --------- --------- ------------
|    4    |   0:24  | 04/09/2014 | <-- date today
 --------- --------- ------------
```

The time is only minutes and seconds. I want to get the total SUM of the time and get the average. The average count is depending on how many new records are added today which is 3.

Record count/s for today (04/09/2014) = 3

New time records for today:

```
0:14
0:32
0:24
```

Total Time for today = 1:10

```
Average = 1:10 / 3
```

Comment: Are you able to get time from database?

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years i can get the time by using mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MySQL Solution**:

```
select 
    avg( str_to_date( time, '%i:%s' ) ) 'avg t in sec', 
    date(date) date
from entries 
group by 2;
```

**Demo** @ [***MySQL 5.6.6 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2109/1)

**Results as observed on my console**:

```
mysql> select
    ->   sum( str_to_date( time, '%i:%s' ) ) t,
    ->   date
    -> from entries
    -> group by 2;
+------+---------------------+
| t    | date                |
+------+---------------------+
|   12 | 2014-03-30 00:00:00 |
|   70 | 2014-04-09 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select
    ->     avg( str_to_date( time, '%i:%s' ) ) 'avg t in sec',
    ->     date(date) date
    -> from entries
    -> group by 2;
+--------------+------------+
| avg t in sec | date       |
+--------------+------------+
|      12.0000 | 2014-03-30 |
|      23.3333 | 2014-04-09 |
+--------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what do you mean 'avg t in sec'?

Comment: @PorkChop try copy all this into mysql query , it maybe special sql command that I don't know

Comment: @PorkChop: Check my updated answer. When you sum up the time, total is `1:10` means `1 min 10 sec` which equals `70 seconds`. And when you average it, it returns `seconds`.

Comment: @Ravinder okay. i get it now, but how could i run this query through php code? :)

Comment: @PorkChop: Use the `avg` query shown in my example with PHP and execute. If required, you can also change the alias name `'avg t in sec'` to `'avg_time'`

Comment: @Ravinder you mean this? "$result = mysql_query("select avg(str_to_date(time_duration, '%i:%s' )) 'avg_time', date(date) date from hsncs_tbl group by 2;");"

Comment: @PorkChop: Yes, it is.

Comment: @Ravinder how do i get the output? should i use this? "$row = mysql_num_rows($result);" and echo $row?

Comment: @PorkChop: You better use `mysqli_` in `PHP`. Some examples on and @ [*mysqli_query*](http://in1.php.net/mysqli_query)